# What is the difference between quantum "system", "register" and "Hilbert space"?

Tags: quantum-state, terminology-and-notation

As far as I can tell, these terms are interchangeable but I am not sure of this.

What is meant by each of the terms "quantum system", "quantum register" and "Hilbert space" in the context of quantum information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *[Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space)* is a well-defined mathematical object, namely, it is a (usually complex) vector space equipped with an inner product, that is [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space) with respect to the associated topology. In the finite-dimensional case, these are all isomorphic to some $\mathbb C^n$.

A *quantum system* is not a mathematical term, and thus probably doesn't have a universally accepted mathematical definition. It just generally refers to a physical system that is being described using the quantum mechanical formalism. It is often interchangeable with *quantum state*, although I'd say the former is used to refer more generally to the physical object, while the latter to the possible *states* the system can be in.
You can mentally identify a *quantum system* with the Hilbert space you use to describe its possible states, if you wish.

A *[quantum register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_register)* is the same as a *quantum system*, but the term is generally preferred in computational-related contexts.